# Issues with Node Polyfills and webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm relatively new to web development, but I'm working on a React project where I'm trying to interface with an AWS database. To install MySql, I ran `npm install mysql`, which did end up importing the module, however I now get the error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '.\node_modules\mysql\lib' BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.`

I've done a lot of reading about Webpack, and I now understand that I just need to add a fallback, presumably in a new file called `webpack.config.js` in the root folder. However, I made it and the error is still there. Here's the exact code I used in the file:

```
module.exports = 
{
    entry:"/src/out.js",

    output:{
        path : "dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    resolve: {
        fallback: {
          "fs": false,
          "tls": false,
          "net": false,
          "path": false,
          "zlib": false,
          "http": false,
          "https": false,
          "stream": false,
          "crypto": false,
          "crypto-browserify": false,
          "timers":false
        } 
      },
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like Webpack is completely ignoring the config file, is it an issue with how I wrote the config file?

If it helps at all, I haven't changed any of the configurations bar installing the MySql module, and to export/compile I just use the `npm start` command, which runs it to a localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - for anyone with the same problem, this is what I did.

When you use `create-react-app` to make the app, it doesn't automatically recognize `webpack.config.js`, so you need to run `npm install react-app-rewired` and create another override file called `config-override.js`. [Full instructions and files found here](https://thecodersblog.com/polyfill-node-core-modules-webpack-5)

Answer (score 0):

Re-add support for Node.js core modules with [node-polyfill-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin):

And install dependency `npm install crypto-browserify` and `npm install util`

With the package installed, add the following to your webpack.config.js:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        // other fallbacks
         "util": require.resolve("util/"),
         "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
      },
    }
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Comment: I downloaded the plugin and added that to webpack.config.js, but none of the errors went away. I even created a new project folder and tried everything from scratch, but I'm still getting the same polyfills error. This makes me think that the Webpack config just isn't configuring anything... is there any way I can know for sure that it is?

Comment: Code updated. Please check with updated code

Comment: The updated code didn't work either - I'm still running into the same error. However, the error message hasn't changed at all, which makes me think that Webpack just isn't recognizing and running the config file - is there any way to see if the file is being recognized?